# Stop page from jumping to top on click with if else

Tags: jquery

I have a button that is toggling my menu (#menu-toggle). When the user clicks the button the page jumps to the top. How can i stop this from happening?

Tried this but it did not work:

```
$('#menu-toggle').click(function(event){
$('.wrap, nav > ul, .wrap > .container:first-child').toggleClass('push');
    event.preventDefault();
if ($('.wrap').hasClass('push')){
    $('.wrap').css('position', 'fixed');
    $('.wrap > .container:first-child > div:first-child').slideUp(500);
} else {
    $('.wrap').css('position', 'relative');
}
});
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<button id="menu-toggle">
  <div id="nav-toggle"><span></span></div>
</button>
<button id="search-toggle"></button>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: _I  have tried this but it disable the if else statement_. Anything going on after a `return` will be ignored.

Comment: ok thanks, but what would work?

Comment: `event.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 0):

a solution may be to put the 
**return fals**e or **event.preventDefault()**  after completing the **`else block`**  and **not before the if statement** ,you can  use something  like this :

```
$('#menu-toggle').click(function(event){
$('.wrap, nav > ul, .wrap > .container:first-child').toggleClass('push');

if ($('.wrap').hasClass('push')){
    $('.wrap').css('position', 'fixed');
    $('.wrap > .container:first-child > div:first-child').slideUp(500);
} else {
    $('.wrap').css('position', 'relative');
}
event.preventDefault(); //equivalent to return false;
});
```